# Calcular tasa de crecimiento

Tags: r, rstudio

Tengo un data frame con datos del PIB desde 1995 hasta 2021. Necesito calcular la tasa de crecimiento anual. Intuyo que el código tendría que ser similar a este:

```
PIB_Crecimiento=(PIB[T]-PIB[T-1]/PIB[T-1]) x 100
```

Pero no consigo determinar "T".

Quizás haya un código más directo para calcular tasas de crecimiento. Agradeceré cualquier indicación.

Gracias!

Comment: Y que es T? y que es PIB es alguna variable que has declarado, que tienes programado ?

Answer (score 1):

Una solución muy fácil usando la librería tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
# Creo unos datos de ejemplo:

data.frame(
  pib = c(10,11, 12, 13), 
  año = c(1995, 1996, 1997, 1998)) -> df

df |> 
  mutate(crecimiento = (pib - lag(pib))/lag(pib)*100) #Atención a los paréntesis para componer la función: quiero que primero resuelva la resta, luego la división. 

  pib  año crecimiento
1  10 1995          NA
2  11 1996   10.000000
3  12 1997    9.090909
4  13 1998    8.333333
```

Aquí uso la función `lag()` para acceder a un vector movido una posición, efectivamente accedo a la fila anterior.

Con R base el problema es que no hay una función que haga lo que hace `lag` (la que se llama así funciona solamente para series de tiempo). Es cuestión de hacer primero una función que da resultados equivalentes a `lag` y luego transformar la columna.

```
milag <- function(x, k = 1){
  c(rep(NA, k), x[1:length(x)-k])}

df |> 
  transform(crecimiento = (pib - milag(pib))/milag(pib)*100)
```

Con el código que tenías podrías lograrlo, pero tendrías que iterar "manualmente" con un `for`. En `R` las operaciones con vectores están vectorizadas, siempre que se puede lo mejor es aprovechar esa característica del lenguaje.

Comment: ¡Muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Si la respuesta te ha servido, recuerda aceptarla y eventualmente darle al +1, es la forma "oficial" de decir Gracias! en Stack Overflow en español, además haces que el contenido perdure y pueda ayudar a otros usuarios.